# Countdown timer not working when app removed from background

Tags: android, listview, timer

In my listview I have srno,name,button and countdowntimer.Button can be clicked when countdown timer is finished.All is working fine.But problem is that when is close my app and open it again countdown timer restarts from beginning.I want countdown timer to run even if i close my app.I have stuck up here from past 3 days Can anyone give me exact code plz.Following is my code-

**Second.java**

```
public class Second extends Activity{

TextView txtsrno,txtflower,txtstatus,txttimeleft;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Model> flowerlist;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        txtsrno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srno);
        txtflower = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buy);
        txttimeleft=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.remtime);


                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                flowerlist = new ArrayList<>();

                flowerlist.add(new Model(1, "Rose",System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800000));
                flowerlist.add(new Model(2, "Sunflower",System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000));
                flowerlist.add(new Model(3, "Lotus",System.currentTimeMillis() + 30000));
                flowerlist.add(new Model(4, "Jasmine",System.currentTimeMillis() + 600000));

                SecondCustom sc = new SecondCustom(this, flowerlist);
                listView.setAdapter(sc);


            }
}
```

**SecondCustom.java**

```
public class SecondCustom extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity a;
    ArrayList<Model> flowerlist;
    private List<Viewholder> lstHolders;
    long timeDiff;



    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (Viewholder holder : lstHolders) {
                    holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    public SecondCustom(Activity a, ArrayList<Model> flowerlist) {
        this.a = a;
        this.flowerlist = flowerlist;
        lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
        startUpdateTimer();
    }


    private void startUpdateTimer() {
        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flowerlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return flowerlist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


public class Viewholder {
        TextView srno, name, ltime;
        Button buy;
        Model mModel;


        public void setData(Model item) {
            mModel = item;
            name.setText(item.name);
            updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
            timeDiff = mModel.expirationTime - currentTime; // Changes -- remove long
            if (timeDiff > 0) {
                int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
                int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                int hours = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                ltime.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

                buy.setClickable(false);

            } else {
                buy.setClickable(true);
                ltime.setText("Buy Now!!");
                buy.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e72929"));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Viewholder viewholder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            LayoutInflater li = a.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.secondcustom, viewGroup, false);
            viewholder.srno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sr);
            viewholder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flow);
            viewholder.buy = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.st);
            viewholder.ltime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lefttime);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            synchronized (lstHolders) {
                lstHolders.add(viewholder);
            }
        } else {
            viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewholder.setData((Model) getItem(i));


        final Model model = flowerlist.get(i);
        viewholder.srno.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getSr()));
        viewholder.name.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getName()));
        viewholder.ltime.setText(valueOf(flowerlist.get(i).getExpirationTime()));



        viewholder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(a, "Purchased" + " " + flowerlist.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen examples with with service but they have implemented on their main page.But since i want in SecondCustom page cant understand how to implement it.

Comment: No i dont want to pause and then start it when app is opened again.I want time must keep running even if app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

> But problem is that when is close my app and open it again countdown timer restarts from beginning.

This is a normal activity workflow, it is re-created when you start it again (after closing it).

> I want countdown timer to run even if i close my app.

Well, then you will need a service or an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). But remember that when your app is in background then you cant touch its UI.

Maybe the best aproach for you will be to save state of your activity when it is put to background and restore when it is shown again, this is a way to save and restore UI state when user switches between apps : [see here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras).

Comment: It can be implemented by service but I dont know how to do it.Can someone give me exact code as me new in Android.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `"Android service example"`? SO is here to help you with specific programming questions, not write entire blocks of code for you

Comment: Create a thread in your Service and from within it do (pseudocode) while(!done) { sleep(1000); /* do some work every 1s*/ }. But service can be killed by system, but only in specific cases. AlarmManager should be more reliable.

Comment: @Denny yes i searched service example but problem is that they are implemented in textview on main page.I want to implement in custom listview so cant understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the time when you exit your app - when you start the app again, look at the saved time, see how much time has passed since then (using System.currentTimeMillis()) and update your timer accordingly.

Comment: How can i implement it in my code.Can anyone give me exact code plz.Have stuck here from past 3 days :(